# Unable to return value inside function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, promise

Unable to return value inside function in node.js . Below is my function which I am calling from another function to get desired value but I am getting undefined.

```
const getBBBMeetingInfo = (meetingID) => {

    let bbbHttp = bbb.http;
    let getMeetingInfo = api.monitoring.getMeetingInfo(meetingID);
    let val;
    bbbHttp(getMeetingInfo).then((result) => {
      let newRes = {};
      newRes = result;
      newRes.meetingID = meetingID;
      if(newRes.returncode == 'FAILED'){
        updateNotificationCallStatus(meetingID)
      }  
      val = newRes.returncode

    });

    return val
}
```

calling fuction like this

```
let bn =  getBBBMeetingInfo(ele.meetingId);
console.log(bn)//undefined
```

I am new to node.js.  Please let me know how I can get it and use it as returned value.

Comment: Can you show the `bbbHttp` function?

Comment: its library  ,   
const bbb = require("bigbluebutton-js");
let bbbHttp = bbb.http;

Comment: It needs to be async (as in async/await) because of the promise

Comment: actually I am calling this let bn =  getBBBMeetingInfo(ele.meetingId); inside other function callback.

Comment: @Bhinal Chauhan here you go - https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/0cb7971d6d8392939c7763911a4daae3